# Equality evaluation of Char and String variables with identical text

Tags: julia

I'm reading text entries from a csv file and testing them against default values that I have stored in an array. In Matlab I had used `isequal(w1,w2)`; however, Julia is more exacting, and `isequal` always reports `false` . In 
trying to figure out why, I looked at the properties of the two variables. For the data from the csv file, `typeof(w2)` renders `SubString{ASCIIString}`; `w2[1]` renders `A`; `typeof(w2[1])` renders `Char`; and `length(w2)` renders `23`. For the default array, `typeof(w1)` renders `Array{ASCIIString,1}`; `w1[1]` renders `APP #2 bias voltage [V]`;`typeof(w1[1])` renders `ASCIIString`; and `length(w1)` renders `1`. 
So it looks as though I have a Char variable on the one hand, and a String variable on the other. I've looked though the documentation and searched online for conversion functions from Char->String or from String->Char, but I haven't found one. 
Should I  convert each text character in each variable to its ASCII equivalent numeric code, and then evaluate equivalence? Or is there a way of stuffing the String text characters into a Char array? 
Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `map(x -> Char(x[1]) , x)` will return the the Chars from your x vector.

Comment: Quite right, thanks - "z1 = map(w1 -> Char(w1[1]), w1)" results in: 
"typeof(z1)" renders "Array{Char,1}", and "z1" renders "1-element 
Array{Char,1}: 'A'". However, "isequal(z1,w2[1])" is still 'false'. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: I can use _isequal(w1,[w2])_ instead of what I had been using _[isequal(w1,w2)]_. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually quite simple, and doesn't have anything to do with String <-> Char conversions.
w1 is a `Vector` of `ASCIIString`, i.e. something like:

```
w1 = ["APP #2 bias voltage [V]"]
```

w2 is a type of string (simply a substring of a larger `ASCIIString`), not a vector.

You simple need to do: `w1[1] == w2`.

Note: it might be nice if Julia threw some sort of "NotComparableError", when you try to compare two things like a Vector of strings and a string.

Here is an example of how Julia's promotion rules handle comparisons between different types of strings (`ASCIIString`, `UTF16String`, `UTF32String`, and `SubString{ASCIIString}`, like you get back from the CSV parser:

```
julia> wasc = "APP #2 bias voltage [V]"
"APP #2 bias voltage [V]"
julia> w16 = utf16("APP #2 bias voltage [V]")
"APP #2 bias voltage [V]"
julia> w32 = utf32("APP #2 bias voltage [V]")
"APP #2 bias voltage [V]"
julia> wsub = SubString(wasc,1,length(wasc))
"APP #2 bias voltage [V]"
julia> wvec = ["APP #2 bias voltage [V]"]
1-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "APP #2 bias voltage [V]"
julia> wvec == wsub
false
julia> wvec[1] == wsub
true
julia> wvec[1] == w16
true
julia> wvec[1] == w32
true
julia> typeof(w32)
UTF32String
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!!  There must be a reason why "typeof(w2)" renders 'substring' rather than just 'string'?  --Thanks again.

Comment: `SubString` is a parameterized type, it's used to return a slice of a larger string, without copying. Like `ASCIIString`, `UTF8String`, `UTF16String` and `UTF32String` it is a subtype of the abstract `AbstractString`. There are a few other subtypes (some may get removed in v0.5), like `RevString`, which efficiently returns a reversed view of a string, without copying.